# React daterangepicker - mobile friendly

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd, daterangepicker

I am using Ant Design in my React project but I can't find a property for the [daterangepicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/) in order to show the calendars in mobile friendly format. It will always show 2 months and the second month doesn't fit the mobile screen. Is there a workaround? I tried to use `react-dates` component which has the `numberOfMonths` property but there is no time picker...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to change the styles coming from the library. Use the exact names as you see them when reviewing in Chrome Dev Tools (the classes from library start with "ant"). In order to do so in your .less file add media queries covering the screens with maximum width of 480px. It's enough to change the following 2 classes:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .ant-calendar-range {
        width: 320px;
    }
    .ant-calendar-range-part {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

And your range picker will display months in column, so they fit small screens:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**SOLUTION 2021**

I came up with this solution, and is to hide the second picker but always leaving the functionality of the following month.

Using styled-components and the panelRender property of the datePicker you can wrap the entire panel in a wrapper that allows you to edit the css classes in mobile and reset them on desktop.

if you don't use styled component feel free to edit the css globally or bind a div with a global class

```
const RangeDatePicker = (props) => {
  const panelRender = (panelNode) => (
    <StyleWrapperDatePicker>
      {panelNode}
    </StyleWrapperDatePicker>
  );

  return <DatePicker.RangePicker  panelRender={panelRender} {...props} />;
};
```

**CSS**

```
export const StyleWrapperDatePicker = styled.div`
  .ant-picker-panel {
    &:last-child {
      width: 0;
      .ant-picker-header {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        .ant-picker-header-prev-btn, .ant-picker-header-view {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
      }

      .ant-picker-body {
        display: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        width: 280px!important;
        .ant-picker-header {
          position: relative;
          .ant-picker-header-prev-btn, .ant-picker-header-view {
            visibility: initial;
          }
        }

        .ant-picker-body {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should change the flex direction to column when you are on mobile view

```
 @media(max-width: 576px) { 
  .ant-picker-panels { 
    flex-direction: column;
  } 
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't allow the page to scroll

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `RangePicker` which will always show 2 months, you could use 2 `DatePicker` with the use of `disabledDate` property.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/oip3r

Comment: `RangePicker` is requested... So I have to use it. Thx for the recommendation though

Answer (score 1):

To me, changing the flex-direction from the default(**row**) to **column** is the best way to go.

```
import { DatePicker } from "and";
import styled from "styled-components";

const RangeDatePicker = (props) => {
  <DatePicker.RangePicker
     panelRender={(panelNode) => (
         <StyledRangePickerContainer>{ panelNode }</StyledRangePickerContainer>
     )}
     {...props}
  />
}
```

CSS

```css
const StyledRangePickerContainer = styled.div`
  @media (max-width: 576px) {
    .ant-picker-panels {
      flex-direction: column !important;
    }
  }
`;
```

Result

[image]

Comment: But it doesn't allow the page to scroll